# Sencha Touch 2 carousel indicator tap events

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2 carousel (see http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/carousel/index.html).
I need to capture the event when the active item is first and the user tries to navigate back.
Also, when the active item is the last and the user tries to navigate forward.

I haven't found on Sencha Touch docs anything close to my needs:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel

Let's start from here:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
fullscreen: true,

defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
},

items: [
    {
        html : 'Item 1',
        style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
    },
    {
        html : 'Item 2',
        style: 'background-color: #759E60'
    },
    {
        html : 'Item 3'
    }
]});
```

Comment: "and the user tries to navigate back" by tapping the indicators ?

Comment: I add navigation buttons on the indicator. When the first item is active and the user taps 'back' the viewport is changed with something else. Same with the last item - when is active and the user taps 'next'. By default, when user taps at the left or right of the indicators, the active carousel item is changed.

Comment: I got the solution for feature reference....

The solution was to modify Sencha Touch' indicator tap event.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/174LEDV5

Comment: @GeorgeI. please post the solution as answer and accept it. It's for future visitors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var activeItem = 0; // initial active carousel item
    Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    id: 'q-car',
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    initialize: function(){
        var caru = Ext.getCmp('q-car'),
            ind = caru.getIndicator();

        ind.onTap = function(e){
            var touch = e.touch,
                box = this.element.getPageBox(),
                centerX = box.left + (box.width / 2),
                centerY = box.top + (box.height / 2),
                direction = this.getDirection(),
                itemsCount = caru.getItems().length-2; // items length includes the indicator bar.

            if(direction === 'horizontal'){
                if(touch.pageX >= centerX){
                    if(activeItem < itemsCount){
                        this.fireEvent('next', this);
                        activeItem++                                                
                    }else{
                        console.log('end of carousel')
                    }
                }else{
                    if(activeItem > 0){
                        this.fireEvent('next', this);
                        activeItem--                                                
                    }else{
                        console.log('begin of carousel')
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            html : 'Item 1',
            style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
        },
        {
            html : 'Item 2',
            style: 'background-color: #759E60'
        },
        {
            html : 'Item 3'
        }
    ]});
```